# Airflow dag not starting

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have `dag` as shown below scheduled to run every day at `00:30`. Somehow dag is not being triggered by `scheduler` at all. I created it yesterday and expected to first run today but it wasn't. What could be the issue? Note that manual run of dag is fine.

```
with DAG(
        dag_id="my_name",
        description='my_name',
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 14, 0, 0),
        schedule_interval="30 0 * * *",
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": False,
        },
) as dag:

    default_args = {
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
    'max_retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
}

    task_my_name = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_name',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_name,
        default_args=default_args,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
        },
    )

    task_final = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_final',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=finalfunction,
    )

    (
        task_my_name >> task_final
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Airflow runs your DAG at the end of **schedule_interval + start_date**.
so here your start date should be past. In your case, it should run at 2023/12/15:030

See docs for more: [apache-airflow-scheduler](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/scheduler.html)